# Insert Excel file in SQL database with AJAX and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ajax

Hi i want to store excel files in a SQL Data base table, but i having some troubles with my code in the server side C#.
So the thing is that i'm taking all those values i need but one of them it's the actual excel file. So I have 2 questions: 
**1) Can I store properly an excel's file in a table just by the use of varbinary(max) data type.** 
**2) if thats so, how i pass that file by ajax to my server code? As i'm catching the users file in js i'm not pretty sure of can i handle it in C#**
Here is my code:

```js
    <script>



        function tryme() {
            var modelx = new Object();

            var depS = document.getElementById("resultDep");
            var catS = document.getElementById("resultCat");
            var schemS = document.getElementById("schemes");

            var wiw = document.getElementById("wiw").value;
            modelx.wiw = wiw;

            var nm = document.getElementById("namePro").value;
            modelx.name = nm;

            var dp = depS.options[depS.selectedIndex].value;
            modelx.dep = dp;

            var ct = catS.options[catS.selectedIndex].value;
            modelx.cat = ct;

            var sch = schemS.options[schemS.selectedIndex].value;
            modelx.schem = sch;
            var myFile = $('#fileinput').prop('files');

            modelx.f = myFile;
            alert(".. / "+ modelx.name +"/" + modelx.cat + " / " + modelx.dep + " / " + modelx.schem
                + " / " + modelx.wiw + " / " +modelx.f);


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '@Url.Action("CreateRequest", "Home")',
                data: "{'Name':'" + modelx.name + "', 'Category':'" + modelx.cat + "',"+
                    "'Department':'" + modelx.dep + "' ," + "'Wiw':'" + modelx.wiw + "',"+
                    "'Scheme':'" + modelx.schem + "' ," + "'File':'" + modelx.f + "'"
                    + "}",
                success: function (Record) {
                },
                Error: function (textMsg) {

                    alert("something got wrong");
                }
            });




        //end function
        }
        
        </script>
```

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

 <label>Departments:</label><br /><select id="resultDep" onchange="GetCategories()">
     <option>-----</option>
 </select>
<br /><br />
<label>Categories:</label><br /><select id="resultCat"></select>
<br /><br />
<label>Scheme:</label><br />
<select id="schemes" required></select>
<br />
<br />
<p>Nombre:  @Session["Name"]</p>
<!--            <p>Area: Innovación tecnológica</p>-->
<p>Tipo de usuario: @Session["Role"]</p>
<p>E-mail: @Session["Correo"]</p>
<p >WIW:@Session["WiW"]</p><br />


<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="hidden" id="wiw" value="@Session["WiW"]" />
    <input type="text" id="namePro" value="" />
    <br />
      <input type="file" id="fileinput" />

    <input type="submit" onclick="tryme()" value="click" />
</form>
```

Server side code

```js
C#

public static bool CreateRequest(string Name, int Category, 
            int Department, string Wiw, int Scheme,
           file? myfile //just here i want to pass that file but i don't know how
            )
        {
         string cs = "";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cs, con))
                {
                // my code...
```

Answer (score 1):

On the client side, change Content-Type from application/json to multipart/form-data

On the c# side, look into the class HttpPostedFileBase

On the sql server side, I’d suggest looking into Sql servers filestream data type

Comment: Hi i look up for HttpPostedFileBase i found some ways to store the file by **path** and storing files in a folder in the server but i want to store my file in a sql base using a queryi'm using **varbinary** data type to store in sql